# VueJS 2: cannot set two-way data-binding for input components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Being quite new to Vue, I ran into the issue when I cannot establish binding between input/select tags inside components and the data inside Vue instance.

Example #1:

`html`

```
<sidebar-select
  :title="UI.sidebar.localeSelect.title"
  :name="UI.sidebar.localeSelect.name"
  :options="UI.sidebar.localeSelect.options"
  :vmodel="selectedLocale">
</sidebar-select>
<sidebar-select
  :title="UI.sidebar.currencySelect.title"
  :name="UI.sidebar.currencySelect.name"
  :options="UI.sidebar.currencySelect.options"
  :vmodel="state.currency">
</sidebar-select>
```

`js - component`

```
Vue.component('sidebar-select', {
  props: ['title', 'name', 'options', 'vmodel'],
  data() {
    return {
      vmodel: this.value
    }
  },
  template: `<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="padding-left:0;padding-right:30px">
  <div class="cg">
    <label :for="name"><h4>{{ title }}</h4></label>
    <select class="form-control form-horizontal" style="max-width: 300px" 
      :name="name"
      v-model="vmodel">
      <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.value">{{ option.text }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>`
});
```

`js - data part`

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedLocale: 'ru',
    user: {
      'ru': {
        name: 'Саша',
        surname: 'Найдович',
        position: 'программист',
        phone: '1234567',
        email: 'jdlfh@jdlbf.com'
      },
      'en': {
        name: 'Alex',
        surname: 'Naidovich',
        position: 'frontend',
        phone: '1234567',
        email: '1234567@email.eu'
      }
    },
    state: {
      locale: 'ru',
      currency: '€',
      /* *** */
    },
    UI: {
      sidebar: {

        localeSelect: {
          title: 'Язык КП',
          name: 'offer-lang',
          options: [
            {value: 'en', text: 'International - English'},
            /* *** */
            {value: 'ru', text: 'Русский'}
          ],
          preSelected: 'ru',
          stateprop: 'locale'
        },

        currencySelect: {
          title: 'Валюта КП',
          name: 'offer-curr',
          options: [
            {value: '$', text: '$ (Dollar)'},
            {value: '€', text: '€ (Euro)'},
            {value: '₤', text: '₤ (UK Фунт)'},
            {value: '₽', text: '₽ (RUS Рубль)'},
            {value: '', text: 'Ввести вручную'}
          ],
          preSelected: '€',
          stateprop: 'currency'
        },
      } /* etc */
    }
  }
});
```

There are 2 errors I run into: `[Vue warn]: The data property "vmodel" is already declared as a prop. Use prop default value instead.` at init and `[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "vmodel"` vhen I try to change selects. I wish to know what am I doing wrong and what would be the best-practice way for this case.

**UPDATE**: the main question is about how to properly use `v-model` two-way-data-binding when passing `v-model` as an argument into the `props` of component.

To be updated: example #2 with text inputs will be added tomorrow (the code is left at work).

Comment: 1 - Look your <SidebarSelect /> component, you are passing vmodel as prop, and you also define it in the data section.
2 - You can't mutate a prop, you have to emit an event with the new value and the parent must update the value and send to the child the new one

Comment: @DobleL thanks. Had kind of the same thought about the 1st error. But could you pls expand the point about the 2nd one? What I've tried is passing a handler as prop, and this handler was able to change data prop, and threw no errors. But when I try to change the state prop from console, the changed values didn't reach the component's view. And, the main question was about how to properly use `v-model` two-way-data-binding when passing `v-model` as an argument into the `props` of component.

Comment: in a theorical scenario, and following the parent-child comunications, you can't mutate a property cuz the parent is not going to notice. the best practice is to emit (this.$emit) some event and handle it within the parent, but you actually can do what you want but using a .sync modifier. ie `vmodel.sync="data"` and then you can mutate in the child and will be syncrhonized with the paren